# Best data compression format available

Tags: compression

I'm sometimes sharing big files (1 GB, Visual Studio C++ Solution) over the internet, but I have very very low upload speed.
So, I'm trying to compress my data into the smallest file as possible.
I don't care much about speed, I and the data reciever have good PC.
My biggest find in the compression was an FreeArc format, which on Ultra settings compressed my source code files from 1 GB to 83.8 MB (8%). Thats pretty good.

However, is here some better compression format? Let me know!
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's better than FreeArc, but I've had success with 7-Zip. http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: @bdr9 Yea, but in my case (VS C++ Solution) 7z's ultra compressed file was 125 MB, FreeArc on ultra (it needs more memory and good cpu) compressed file was 83 MB.

Answer (score 5):

The efficiency of a given compression format is dependent on the type of information being compressed.  Since you don't specify what type of data is contained in the big files you wish to compress, here is a comparison of common compression algorithms in terms of deflate size vs compression time (CPU power) for common types of data: [Comparison of compression algorithms](http://binfalse.de/2011/04/04/comparison-of-compression/).

If you're not sure about the content, in most cases the [LZMA algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm) which is used by default by [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) (as .7z algorithm, which is LZMA & LZMA2).

Comment: Its a Visual Studio C++ solution.

Comment: You should edit your post with that information.